# Migrating my site to HTTPS

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

I installed SSL on my server, works great.  Let's say I have 10 html/php pages.

Here's where I'm confused as to what's best for SEO:

**In my .htaccess file, am I doing a site wide (for all 10 pages) 301 redirect:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?    (.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**Or should I redirect each of the 10 pages:**

page1:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page1.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/page1.php/$1 [L,R=301]
```

page2:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page2.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/page2.php/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: SEO-related questions might be a better fit for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I use for years and works fine

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

No need to set 301 status, Apache will automatically set `302 Found` status and it's fine for Google since my website ranking was increased after doing that.

Comment: just to clarify, it's okay to do a site-wide redirect for all pages?

Comment: Yes it's totally fine. It's working for all requests including images, requests with GET parameters and etc.